# Ошибка VK.NET The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken]

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, asp.net-core, vknet

Пытаюсь реализовать простой ответ бота на сообщение, при получении сообщения с сервера выдает ошибку:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/problem+json;charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie:

Date: Fri, 08 Oct 2021 11:38:36 GMT

{
  "type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title":"One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status":400,
  "traceId":"|51749231-41cb231bd26466a4.",
  "errors":{
    "$.object":["The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken]. Path: $.object | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 41."]
  }
}
```

```
[Serializable]
public class Updates
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Тип события
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Объект, инициировавший событие
    /// Структура объекта зависит от типа уведомления
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("object")]
    public JObject Object { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// ID сообщества, в котором произошло событие
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("group_id")]
    public long GroupId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Секретный ключ. Передается с каждым уведомлением от сервера
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("secret")]
    public string Secret { get; set; }
}
```

контроллер:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CallbackController : ControllerBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Конфигурация приложения
        /// </summary>
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly IVkApi _vkApi;
        public CallbackController(IVkApi vkApi, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _vkApi = vkApi;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Callback([FromBody] Updates updates)
        {
            // Проверяем, что находится в поле "type" 
            switch (updates.Type)
            {
                // Если это уведомление для подтверждения адреса
                case "confirmation":
                    // Отправляем строку для подтверждения 
                    return Ok(_configuration["Config:Confirmation"]);

                case "message_new":
                    {
                        // Десериализация
                        var msg = Message.FromJson(new VkResponse(updates.Object));

                        // Отправим в ответ полученный от пользователя текст
                        _vkApi.Messages.Send(new MessagesSendParams
                        {
                            RandomId = new DateTime().Millisecond,
                            PeerId = msg.PeerId.Value,
                            Message = msg.Text
                        });; 

                        break;
                    }
            }
            // Возвращаем "ok" серверу Callback API
            return Ok("ok");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ошибка возникает при отправке какого-то запроса? Или когда?

Comment: когда от VK приходит объект нового сообщения. что то не так с десериализацией. var msg = Message.FromJson(new VkResponse(updates.Object));